# How can you avoid leaking memory when removing from a doubly-linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list

Suppose I have a doubly-linked list such as

```
class list
{
    /*...*/

private:
    struct node
    {
       node* prev;
       node* next;
       int* value;
    }

    node* first; //NULL if none
    node* last; //NULL if none

    /*...*/
}
```

If I want to write a function that removes the first node and returns a pointer to its value, will this implementation leak memory?

```
int* returnFrontValue()
{
   if(list_is_Empty())
        throw -1;
   else
   {
        node* v = first;
        int* returnMe = v->value;

        first = first->next;
        if(!first)
            last = NULL;

        delete v;
        first->prev = NULL;

        return returnMe;
   }
}
```

I'm curious if this implementation leaks memory because `returnMe` points to an int that is dynamically allocated.  Would it be better to have an `int returnMe = *(v->value);` and return `&returnMe;` at the end instead?

Do I have to `delete v->value;` explicitly before I `delete v;`?  I'm confused as to how deleting memory works when you have various pointers.

Comment: Returning the address of a local variable? Definitely not better.

Comment: Why does each node have a pointer to a dynamically allocated `int`, instead of simply an `int` member?

Comment: @interjay if it is a member, `delete v` will destroy it

Comment: @Evgeni so? Copy it before it is deleted.

Comment: @jalf yes, return-by-value would be a solution.

Comment: I think valgrind deserves a mention here. I find it extremely helpful in such situations. Just saying.

Comment: @axiom: helpful in what, exactly? If you write your code first, and then use a tool to check if it leaks memory, you're doing it wrong. Design it so that it doesn't leak memory *in the first place*. This requires you to *understand* your code, but I don't consider that a bad thing. :)

Comment: @jalf True, i totally concur. I was just saying that there may be tricky situations where you are not sure/can't figure things out exactly and tools like valgrind may help you pinpoint the problem. So it's sort of good to know. Sometimes the reasons may be non obvious ( eg. a call to `getline()`, who calls `malloc()` but you need to free) and that's when tools like these come in handy. :-)

Answer (score 2):

We can't see how the `int` was allocated, but I'll take your word for it that it was dynamically allocated (as a separate allocation from the node, which you delete).

In that case no, you haven't leaked anything *yet*, but you're tempting fate. It's not a leak because a pointer to the `int` still exists, so it can still be deleted. But now the responsibility rests with the caller. If I call `returnFrontCaller`, I get a pointer to a value, *which I then have to call `delete` on when I'm done with it*.

That's not very intuitive. Generally `new`/`delete` calls should be matched in the same place. If I call `new`, I also call `delete`. If the `new` call happened elsewhere, I wouldn't expect that calling `delete` was my responsibility.

But why is the value dynamically allocated at all`Why do you store an`int*`instead of an`int`? Why does the function return a pointer to the int, instead of a copy of it?

If you made that change, no memory management would be necessary. The caller would get an int, and wouldn't have to worry about "who calls `delete`".

Alternatively, you could use a smart pointer class to wrap it, and to handle the memory management.

Comment: So in this example, what actually happens when I delete a node?  It contains three pointers, do I have to delete them all individually?

Comment: When you delete a node, then, as mentioned, the pointer to the int* within is left hanging. If the caller loses it and didn't delete, there's a leak. The other pointers refer to existing nodes that are not going to be removed by this delete operation, so they do not need to be (and should not be, by this delete call) deleted.

Comment: When you delete a node, first the class' destructor is called, and then every member of the node class has its destructor called. For raw pointers, this has no effect (in particular, it will **not** delete whatever the pointer is pointing to).